# Changing error message to pop up message

Tags: php

I am having a problem resolving my code here.. I've seen this code and edit it by my self but I want to change the error message to pop up alert, by the client entered an existing value after submitting the pop up message will appear and say Sample Code is already in use

```
if($scode != '') {
    $qry = "SELECT * FROM toxintablemonitoring WHERE sampleCode='$scode'";
    $result = mysql_query($qry);
    if($result) {
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            $errmsg_arr[] = 'Sample Code already in use';
            $errflag = true;
        }
        @mysql_free_result($result);
    }
    else {
        die("Query failed");
    }
}

if($errflag) {
    $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
    session_write_close();
    header("location: sample_input_monitoring_toxin.php");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0):

I m not sure but you can replace your code and try.

replace `$errmsg_arr[] = 'Sample Code already in use';`

To `echo $errmsg_arr[] = '<script>alert("Sample Code already in use")</script>';`